# How do I accept the download prompt on the firefox webdriver using selenium in JAVA?

Tags: java, selenium

I am testing a page I am building and I was hoping to find out if it is possible to accept the download prompt using selenium? I am using the Firefox Webdriver.

Comment: Selenium is not able to accept OS level dialogs, it was not built for that - the answer below *should* work.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839544/using-selenium-webdrivers-method-browser-helperapps-neverask-savetodisk-how-ca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to set have your test use a firefox profile that is setup to automatically accept the download prompt. See [here](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles) for help creating a new profile. To use this profile in your test see the top answer to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031253/what-profile-does-selenium-webdriver-use-by-default).  However I also recommend reading [this](http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/), which will explain why you don't actually need to download the files to test that your download functionality is working.

Comment: The link to explain why you don't need to download files is dead. It's now located here: http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/testing/webdriver/2012/07/25/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt.html

Answer (score 5):

You can try using the following code, for downloading a zip file:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
//MIME type for zip file "application/zip"

profile.setPreference("browser,helperapps.neverAsk.SaveToDisk", "application/zip");

// 0 = desktop, 1 = default download folder , 2 = user defined location.
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",0);

driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
baseUrl = " http://www.yourwebsite.com ";
driver.get(baseUrl);
driver.findElement(By.id("downloadFile")).click;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you choose Sikuli, it is too simple.
Add sikuli-java.jar file in build path, install Picpick soft, save images of save file, ok button using Picpick.
Type the following commands

```
new Screen().click(new Pattern("E:\\simage\\save.png")); //here e:\\..is image file path
new Screen().click(new Pattern("E:\\simage\\ok.png"));
```

It's over.

Answer (score -1):

Yes sikuli is simple solution for that you can use that