# Automatically download for every file type on firefox using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I've noticed this general format for auto saving in selenium in other posts

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", 'PATH TO DESKTOP')
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/x-gzip")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

But I'm downloading files from a source where I won't know what type will the files be. I've tried regex but it does not seem to work either

Answer (score 3):

As to my knowledge of Selenium, there isn't a way to download all file types. You will have to list out all the required file types.

Here is a list of types: [Link](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html)

Edit: Try the suggestions provided here: [how can i download a file automatically on click of a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839544/using-selenium-webdrivers-method-browser-helperapps-neverask-savetodisk-how-ca)

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm posting my suggestion for this issue, taking as an example the Brazilian Covid-19 files from the Ministry of Health:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
firefox_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
firefox_options.add_argument('--headless')
firefox_options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
firefox_options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
firefox_options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", 'your directory') #Do not forget to add your download path!
firefox_options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/x-7z-compressed;application/x-rar-compressed;application/zip")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_options)
driver.get("https://covid.saude.gov.br")
csv_button=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/app-root/ion-app/ion-router-outlet/app-home/ion-content/div[1]/div[2]/ion-button")
csv_button.click()
```

I hope this code might help someone with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the combination of falsing the alwaysAsk and never ask to save and then specifying the file extension.

set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force"), False

set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/zip;application/gz")

```
se = Service(gecko_path)
op = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
op.add_argument('--headless')
op.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
op.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
op.set_preference("browser.download.dir", my_dir) 
op.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
op.set_preference("browser.download.improvements_to_download_panel", True)
op.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/zip;application/gz")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=se, options=op)
```

basically what Abdinardo Oliveira said.